# C++ Unexpected Token errors

Tags: c++, netbeans, syntax, stack, syntax-error

I am creating a project for C++ that takes an existing .txt file, reads the lines in, and creates another file that is in reverse order relative to the initial file. I am currently trying to create a function that takes the file as a parameter, reads each line individually, pushes each line into a stack, and returns the stack, such that I will then be able to use the stack to create and fill the new file.

```
`
//Takes the given file object and reverses the order
//of the lines by pushing each line into a stack.
stack<string>  reverseStack(ifstream inFile){
    stack<string> inverse;
    string currentLine;
    while(getline(inFile, currentLine){
        inverse.push(currentLine)
    }
    return inverse;
} `
```

At this point, I have a couple of questions.

1) The line with `return inverse` keeps throwing two errors. "Unexpected token: return" and "Unexpected token: inverse". If I understand correctly, this means that the function is not expecting a return statement, so I can only assume that I have a syntax problem here. Is there something wrong with my code? Any suggestions on a solution or a better way of producing the same result is greatly appreciated.

2)What would be the syntax for returning a pointer to a stack, or is that not something that can be done? (ie `*stack<string>` as the return value?)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The mistake has been corrected. There is a missing end parentheses for the while loop!

Comment: `inverse.push(currentLine)` this line is missing a semicolon.

Comment: You're missing a closing paren in the `while` condition.

Comment: Oh my... you are correct. However, I just corrected that and I still have the two errors. Thanks!

Comment: Is that a stray character at the last paren, or did I just squash a bug on my screen?  Hopefully it is poor editing and not actually in your code.

Comment: Ah, Jim you are correct, that solved the problem, thanks! Sometimes an extra set of eyes is all you need!